# Video Player using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, video, video-capture, emgucv

I want to make a video player with detection of objects using Emgu CV. I'd like to start with reading from a video source file and that is where I got an error. In line:

```
Capture capture = new Capture(@"C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Film/parrot.avi");
```

there is an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to create capture from `C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Film/parrot.avi`

I have tried many combinations and different source types like AVI, WMV, MPEG and still got the exception. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem. If this question is still open then try adding:

```
opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll
```

(XXX is your emgucv version) to ur project's exe folder (Debug/Release). FFmpeg is used by `opencv` for handling video.

P.S.:`opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll` is located in extracted `emgucv/bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Emgu CV that you are using? If it is 2.4.10 then I suggest you to use the [3.0.0 version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/3.0.0-alpha/). I have encountered the same problem when I use the most current stable version (2.4.10), but it seems to be patched in the latest alpha version (3.0.0). Now, I can easily capture usb camera, video file, or RTSP stream (IP Camera) using Emgu CV Capture class.

Probably you have solved this problem by now, however I hope this information will also be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for some days, I could not read nor write a video on the Desktop. No error on initialization, but a `Capture` with `Width and Height = 0` returning `null` frames.

It started working simply by changing the path to:

```
".\parrot.avi"
```

This happened to me on Win8.1 using Emgu 3.1.0.2282b